# Java on Mac 10.11.6: code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present

Tags: java, oracle, macos, ant

I'm trying to follow the instructions provided by Oracle for packaging a Java App for distribution on a Mac.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

I'm using a Mac running OS 10.11.6.  Everything works fine until I get to the code signing step.  After scouring the net I have created the following ant script snippet.

```
<property name="MyApp.app" location="dist/ButtonDemo.app"/>
<property name="jdk" value="jdk1.8.0_101.jdk"/>

<exec executable="chmod">
    <arg line="-R a+w ${MyApp.app}"/>
</exec>
<apply executable="codesign">
    <arg line="-f -s 'Developer ID Application: MyName'"/>
    <fileset dir="${MyApp.app}/Contents/PlugIns/${jdk}" />
</apply>
<exec executable="codesign">
    <arg line="-f -s 'Developer ID Application: MyName' ${MyApp.app}"/>
</exec>
<!-- verify codesign -->
<exec executable="codesign" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-d --verbose=4 --strict ${MyApp.app}"/>
</exec>
<!-- verify gatekeeper -->
<exec executable="spctl" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="--assess --verbose=4 --type execute ${MyApp.app}"/>
</exec>
```

I get the following output.

```
clean:
[delete] Deleting directory /Users/mike/ButtonDemo/components-ButtonDemoProject/dist/ButtonDemo.app

bundle-buttonDemo:
[bundleapp] Creating app bundle: ButtonDemo

sign:
[exec] Executable=/Users/mike/ButtonDemo/components-ButtonDemoProject/dist/ButtonDemo.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher
[exec] Identifier=components.ButtonDemo
[exec] Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
[exec] CodeDirectory v=20200 size=341 flags=0x0(none) hashes=5+3 location=embedded
[exec] Hash type=sha256 size=32
[exec] CandidateCDHash sha1=8e4ec99904729d3faf45b8d5f26048d16a9f11c5
[exec] CandidateCDHash sha256=1feeb3eb8479ddfdf25e09cc5660e992f52bda06
[exec] Hash choices=sha1,sha256
[exec] CDHash=1feeb3eb8479ddfdf25e09cc5660e992f52bda06
[exec] Signature size=8919
[exec] Authority=Developer ID Application: MyName (XXXX)
[exec] Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
[exec] Authority=Apple Root CA
[exec] Timestamp=Sep 13, 2016, 2:47:41 AM
[exec] Info.plist entries=16
[exec] TeamIdentifier=XXXX
[exec] Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=4
[exec] Internal requirements count=1 size=184
[exec] /Users/mike/ButtonDemo/components-ButtonDemoProject/dist/ButtonDemo.app: code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present

BUILD FAILED
/Users/mike/ButtonDemo/components-ButtonDemoProject/build.xml:46: exec returned: 1
```

A simple check of the application bundle at dist/ButtonDemo.app/Contents/Resources shows that there are resources.  Why do I get this error?

Comment: Is the last line, `q/exec>` in your script a typo?

Comment: @Rao it was a typo. Hopefully it is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I am embarrassed to say that I made things much more difficult than they had to be. Simply codesigning the jdk plug-in before signing the application itself is needed. This is the only change needed to make the ButtonDemo.app work.